# Missing type in composite literal while working with string[][] in map in golang

Tags: go, multidimensional-array, glide-golang

This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
type person struct {
        //name  [][]string{};
        name [][]string
    }  

func main() {
var people = map[string]*person{}

people["first person"] = &person{name:{{"My name","30"}}}
    fmt.Println(people["first person"])
}
```

I have an error:

> missing type in composite literal

I want output as `[[My name,30]]`

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example. You must declare type of composed literal before using.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type person struct {
    //name  [][]string{};
    name [][]string
}

func main() {
    var people = map[string]*person{}

    people["first person"] = &person{name: [][]string{{"John", "30"}}}
    fmt.Println(people["first person"])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `type` while creating an instance pointer and initializing it, it should be:

```
&person{name: [][]string{{"My name, 30"}}}
```

Below is the working example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type person struct {
    name [][]string
}

func main() {
    var people = map[string]*person{}
    people["first person"] = &person{name: [][]string{{"My name, 30"}}}
    fmt.Println(people["first person"].name)
}
```